# old rs232 trackball must be restarted after every restart

Tags: mouse

I have an old trackball that I am very happy with.
I've got it to run on Ubuntu 14.04 with a USB to RS232 converter.

Every time I start the computer I will start a terminal and input the command `sudo inputattach --microsoft /dev/ttyUSB0`

How do I get it to run automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have solved it the solution is here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialMouseHowto